# NodeJS clustering sending all the request to one worker (Windows)

Tags: node.js

I am using a Windows 7 machine to test clustering in NodeJS.

The code is below:

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
var http = require('http');
var numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;

     if (cluster.isMaster) { 
     // Fork workers.
     for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
        cluster.fork();
     }

     cluster.on('exit', function (worker, code, signal) {
        console.log('worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' died');
     });

     cluster.on('listening', function(worker, address) {
        console.log("A worker with #" + worker.id + " is now connected to " + address.address + ":" + address.port);        
     });
   } else {
      // Workers can share any TCP connection
      // In this case its a HTTP server
      http.createServer(function (req, res) {
          console.log(cluster.worker.id + ' is responding..!!!');
          var j = 0;
          //long running task
          for (var i = 0; i < 10000000000; i++) {
             j++;
          }        
         res.writeHead(200);
         res.end("hello world\n");
     }).listen(8080);

   }
```

When I run this code, it looks like all the request are sent to last worker that was created. All the remaining workers are just sitting idle while all the requests are being processed by the node that was created last in the sequential order.

I have tried to do some reach but it seems that no one has reported this yet. I saw a post on Stack Overflow with same issue and there is no solution. I am using Node v0.10.26.

Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: I test the code by issuing requests from two different computers. It seems that one worker is for one computer and another worker is for the other. Further reading: [What’s New in Node.js v0.12: Cluster Round-Robin Load Balancing](http://strongloop.com/strongblog/whats-new-in-node-js-v0-12-cluster-round-robin-load-balancing/)

Comment: How are you creating the requests?  In some cases (web browsers, for example) a single TCP connection will be used for multiple http requests.

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped. I was using Chrome to make multiple request and it sent to same worker node. But when I used different browsers, all the worker nodes are working.. Thank you again for all the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer is for others if they have the same issue. Use different browsers to make HTTP requests which will make sure that different workers are being used.

Comment: What about load testing all cluster? I loaded loadtest module and it loads only single worker so performance is same for a laptop or desktop didnot matter.

Answer (score 1):

I've just used two browsers + curl from command line.
I've got the same result: http://prntscr.com/8fxx4g

But correct answer is here [clustering in node.js is not working. Only one worker is always responding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25391551/clustering-in-node-js-is-not-working-only-one-worker-is-always-responding#answer-25393141):

> @dandavis said in the comments is true: cluster does not do round-robin load balancing so, as long as Worker 1 is available for requests, it will handle them.

Answer (score 0):

require('os').cpus().length is number of logical processors .
if you go to taskManager -> Performance -> CPU , you will see number of logicalProcessor