# clustering in node.js is not working. Only one worker is always responding

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am practising clustering in node.js I am having a two core CPU. I created two workers and each worker runs a simple http server. Server response callback will block for 5 sec to give next request to other worker. To verify workers are working parallel, I have opened multiple tabs in Firefox and refreshed each. problem is always(99%) only one worker is responding requests that was make by refreshing tabs. Only one request is being served by one worker and all other requests are blocked until that worker is finished. My code is here
CODE:

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
var http = require('http');



if (cluster.isMaster) {
    var cpus = require('os').cpus().length;
    console.log('No of cpus:' + cpus);
    console.log(require('os').cpus());

    for (var i = 0; i < cpus; i++) {
        cluster.fork();
    }

    cluster.on('fork', function(worker) {
        console.log('worker:' + worker.id + " is forked");
    });
    cluster.on('online', function(worker) {
        console.log('worker:' + worker.id + " is online");
    });
    cluster.on('listening', function(worker) {
        console.log('worker:' + worker.id + " is listening");
    });
    cluster.on('disconnect', function(worker) {
        console.log('worker:' + worker.id + " is disconnected");
    });
    cluster.on('exit', function(worker) {
        console.log('worker:' + worker.id + " is dead");
    });

} else {
    http.createServer(function(req, res) {

        console.log('worker:' + cluster.worker.id + " going to send response ");
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end("hello world. worker: " + cluster.worker.id);
        var stop = new Date().getTime();
        while (new Date().getTime() < stop + 5000) {;
        }
    }).listen(8000);
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
20 Aug 00:36:11 - [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
20 Aug 00:36:12 - [nodemon] starting `node cluster.js`
No of cpus:2
[ { model: 'Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     E4500  @ 2.20GHz',
    speed: 2200,
    times: { user: 2264671, nice: 0, sys: 698343, idle: 5965109, irq: 98812 } },
  { model: 'Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     E4500  @ 2.20GHz',
    speed: 2200,
    times: { user: 2466000, nice: 0, sys: 502562, idle: 5959203, irq: 4609 } } ]
worker:1 is forked
worker:2 is forked
worker:2 is online
worker:1 is online
worker:2 is listening
worker:1 is listening
worker:1 going to send response
worker:1 going to send response
worker:1 going to send response
worker:1 going to send response
worker:1 going to send response
worker:1 going to send response
worker:1 going to send response
worker:1 going to send response
worker:1 going to send response
worker:1 going to send response
worker:1 going to send response
worker:1 going to send response
worker:1 going to send response
worker:1 going to send response
worker:1 going to send response
worker:1 going to send response
worker:1 going to send response
worker:1 going to send response
worker:1 going to send response
worker:1 going to send response
```

I have noticed one thing. If I force reload(ctrl+f5) the tab, then both workers is responding one after other.
OUTPUT:

```
worker:1 going to send response
worker:2 going to send response
worker:1 going to send response
worker:2 going to send response
worker:1 going to send response
worker:2 going to send response
worker:1 going to send response
worker:2 going to send response
worker:1 going to send response
worker:2 going to send response
worker:1 going to send response
worker:2 going to send response
worker:1 going to send response
worker:2 going to send response
worker:1 going to send response
worker:2 going to send response
worker:1 going to send response
worker:2 going to send response
worker:1 going to send response
worker:2 going to send response
worker:1 going to send response
worker:2 going to send response
worker:2 going to send response
worker:1 going to send response
worker:2 going to send response
worker:1 going to send response
worker:2 going to send response
worker:1 going to send response
worker:2 going to send response
```

I am confused what,s happening here for normal refresh(f5) and force reload( ctrl + f5 ). help me to figure it out...!

Comment: this all looks fine. if worker1 can handle the traffic, why bother worker2? if worker2 never ever logged, it would be a problem, but i see this pattern a lot on fake/test traffic loads.

Comment: yes it is a fake/traffic load. I am experimenting with cluster framework. problem is only one request is being served by one worker and all other requests are blocked until that worker is finised.

Comment: and i'm telling you it's not a problem. cluster doesn't go round-robin, it goes on needs and surpluses and determined mainly by the OS. think of it like the Northstar engine that shuts down un-needed pistons when coasting in the city.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. My problem is if 10 requests arrived with each request takes 5 sec to serve. then responding with two worker will take 25 sec all the request and responding with one worker will take 50 sec all the request. My problem is even though I created two workers, only one worker is working hence it takes 50 sec to serve all request. I am trying to figure out why second worker is not working.

Comment: actually, in both cases, they should all return in ~5 seconds... it's only because you're killing the CPU in a while loop that your problem is a problem. on real code, that won't happen.

Comment: About 2 years late, but the clusters will not start working until you've reached a certain threshold. For me, it was about 1.5gb ram usage: https://camo.githubusercontent.com/d04c1918bdeacc72f2b79504aa7eaf1e909920bb/68747470733a2f2f692e6779617a6f2e636f6d2f62316565396361656163373132633365316261306638343331366366383461642e706e67

Answer (score 7):

TIL on the surface node clustering does not appear to do what it says it does (at least to me).

I was in the same situation you were, observing the same worker process always being given a request when I spawned them synchronously from a browser. A colleague of mine used fiddler to replay ~20 requests at once. When all of those requests hit the server very fast, faster than the cluster manager can pass them off to workers (I'm guessing), then you will see additional workers being invoked with requests.

It seems that once the manager hands off the request to a worker, it doesn't know/care about the worker blocking. It just knows that there is only one request in the pipe and there is no need to give that request to anyone other than the first worker because, as far as the manager knows, he's available.

Comment: The main thing is to send requests concurrently e.g. with `ab` tool. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `while` loop you have in your response code could be causing some serious problems. You should be using a `setTimeout` there if you want to simulate a long running request.

Try this for your worker instead:

```
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    console.log('worker:' + cluster.worker.id + " going to send response ");
    setTimeout(function() {
       res.writeHead(200);
       res.end("hello world. worker: " + cluster.worker.id);
    }, 5000);
}).listen(8000);
```

That being said, what @dandavis said in the comments is true: `cluster` does not do round-robin load balancing so, as long as `Worker 1` is available for requests, it will handle them. Using `setTimeout` like I suggested will actually make your workers **more** available to handle requests so it's likely that you'll only see `Worker 1` handle requests if you're just hitting the server manually from a browser. You might need some sort of load testing script to see both workers handling requests.

As for the difference you're seeing between *F5* and *CTRL-F5*, my best guess is that your browser is keeping the connection to the server alive so, when you just use *F5*, it uses the same connection which will always go to the same worker. When you use *CTRL-F5* it's actually closing the connection that it had before and therefor could connect to either worker on the next request.

Comment: Hi Mike. I'm doing a node course and have come across a similar example, which is not working for me either. I realise the example is contrived but the purpose of it is to block the event loop and therefore to show that another worker in the cluster will handler another request in parallel. The suggestion of using setTimeout will not block the event loop because it will use the thread pool, if I understand correctly, therefore negating the point of the exercise.