In Node.js fork & cluster not loading instance as expected
I am trying to implement fork and cluster module and below is my code.
const cluster = require("node:cluster");
const http = require("node:http");
const OS = require("node:os");

console.log(OS.cpus().length);

if(cluster.isMaster){
    console.log(`Master process ${process.pid} is running`);
    cluster.fork()
    cluster.fork()
}else{
    console.log(`Worker ${process.pid} started`);
    const server = http.createServer((req, res)=>{
        if(req.url === "/"){
            res.writeHead(200, {"content-type": "text/plain"});
            res.end("Home Page");
        }
        else if (req.url === "/slow-page"){
            for(let i=0; i < 6000000000; i++){}
            res.writeHead(200, {"content-type": "text/plain"});
            res.end("Slow Page");
        }
    });
    
    server.listen(8000, ()=> console.log("Server is running on port 8000"));
}

Ideally, while reload both home page and slow page from above code, home page should load quickly than slow page, but in my case it is not working as expected.
Can some one help me what changes should require in my code?
Ref. : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SHR-KmfRIsU&list=PLC3y8-rFHvwh8shCMHFA5kWxD9PaPwxaY&index=61

I think your problem all requests goes to first worker, to check this just add log when request come like console.log('Request comes, PID:' process.pid) . I checked this on my Windows: Only 1 request out of 15 was accepted by second worker
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25391551/clustering-in-node-js-is-not-working-only-one-worker-is-always-responding#answer-25393141

Consider handling some errors

@MehriddinNozimov: Yes, you are right. How can I overcome this problem from above code. The link i have shared in my question, it is working fine in video.

I think problem is related to Windows, to fix this you have to use load-balancing mechanism
