# Node.js Cluster doesn't improve no. of transactions per second as claimed by some blogs

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance

I tried node clusters without any performance improvement. May be I might be measuring it wrongly.

Using **Node.js 7.4.0**

```
server.js

const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
  }
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end("Hello World!");
}).listen(4002);
```

I followed this tutorial to create cluster server http://rowanmanning.com/posts/node-cluster-and-express/

```
cluster.js

const cluster = require('cluster');
const http = require('http');
const numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }

  cluster.on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
    console.log(cluster.worker.id);
    cluster.fork();
  });
} else {
  http.createServer((req, res) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    }
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    res.end("Hello World!");
  }).listen(4001);
}
```

I can see pids for master and workers on 4 cores when I do

```
$ps axl | grep node

0     0  8799  8789  20   0 682196 28056 ep_pol Sl+  pts/1      0:00 node index.js
0     0  8805  8799  20   0 682196 27708 ep_pol Sl+  pts/1      0:00 /usr/bin/nodejs /home/ubuntu/index.js
0     0  8811  8799  20   0 682196 27608 ep_pol Sl+  pts/1      0:00 /usr/bin/nodejs /home/ubuntu/index.js
0     0  8812  8799  20   0 682196 27756 ep_pol Sl+  pts/1      0:00 /usr/bin/nodejs /home/ubuntu/index.js
0     0  8818  8799  20   0 682196 27604 ep_pol Sl+  pts/1      0:00 /usr/bin/nodejs /home/ubuntu/index.js
```

As ***Rowan*** claims 4x performance increase, I barely got any performance out of clustering.

My siege results on **t2.xlarge AWS instance (4 core) ubuntu machine**.

```
server.js - $siege -c100 -t1M http://xx.xx.xx.xx:4002/

Transactions:              13545 hits
Availability:              100.00 %
Elapsed time:              59.39 secs
Data transferred:          0.16 MB
Response time:             0.19 secs
Transaction rate:          228.07 trans/sec
Throughput:                0.00 MB/sec
Concurrency:               42.30
Successful transactions:   13545
Failed transactions:       0
Longest transaction:       11.61
Shortest transaction:      0.02
```

Now cluster.js

```
cluster.js - $siege -c100 -t1M http://xx.xx.xx.xx:4001/

Transactions:              13223 hits
Availability:              100.00 %
Elapsed time:              59.96 secs
Data transferred:          0.15 MB
Response time:             0.16 secs
Transaction rate:          220.53 trans/sec
Throughput:                0.00 MB/sec
Concurrency:               35.95
Successful transactions:   13223
Failed transactions:       0
Longest transaction:       11.56
Shortest transaction:      0.02
```

Surprisingly, cluster.js performed poorly compared to server.js.

Am I doing something wrong? Is it a change in node.js version? or are these claims false?

https://keyholesoftware.com/2015/01/26/improve-node-js-performance-by-turning-it-into-a-clusterfork/

https://medium.com/node-and-beyond/the-incomplete-collection-of-node-js-performance-tips-94cc712661bd#.lmd19k2u1

https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-a-node-js-cluster-for-speeding-up-your-apps/

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you confirm that your call `.cpus().length;` is returning `4`?  In my experience that API can be kinda funky.  You can also do the poor man's `console.log()` everywhere.  You should see the number of logs reflect the number of clusters you're running.

Comment: Oops, you have the `Hello world` log, is that reflecting something intuitive?

Comment: Yes it does..! It got 4 cores if i print console.log(require('os').cpus());

Comment: Why do you have a useless for-loop in your code?

Comment: @TheDembinski But the blog profiled on Hello World output? Should I add some process and profile it?

Comment: Yea. The clusters will only do their round-robin thing if they have to.  Ill provide an answer.

Answer (score 1):

So this is similar to:

[NodeJS clustering sending all the request to one worker (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22314045/nodejs-clustering-sending-all-the-request-to-one-worker-windows)

and

[clustering in node.js is not working. Only one worker is always responding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25391551/clustering-in-node-js-is-not-working-only-one-worker-is-always-responding#answer-25393141)

Try something like:

```
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    console.log('worker:' + cluster.worker.id + " going to send response ");

//(Heavy I/O operation...followed by res.send(result))

}).listen(8000);
```

Comment: Let me profile this and accept as answer with new stats. Thank you

Comment: Additionally - if you dont see any change with that, try something that can fire of multiple requests.  Like: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html

Comment: But this doesn't have any CPU consuming operation so it seems its not really an interesting test of clustering.  This shouldn't even need or benefit from clustering.

Comment: Agreed.  I feel like the take-away should be: "Do anything that *consumes* a cluster" - like a heavy I/O operation.  My snippet doesnt reflect that idea at all. Will edit.

Comment: @TheDembinski request per second didn't improve much with apache benchmark too. :(

Comment: Cool. Thank you guys. I will try a Heavy I/O operation and benchmark it.